# Perl Command Understanding

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I have been working on a product code to resolve an issue but am stuck on a line of code

Can anyone help me understand what exactly does this command do?

```
perl -MText::CSV -lne 'BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()} print join "|", $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)' /home/daily/${FULL_FILENAME} > /home/output.txt
```

I think its to copy the file to my home location with some transformations but not sure exactly

Comment: This isn't a tutoring service, you need to ask a specific question. What part of it don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly broken program that translates a comma-separated values (CSV) file to a pipe-separated values file.

The particular command-line switches are documented in [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun). This is a "one-liner", so you can read about those to see what's going on there.

The Text::CSV module deals with CSV files, and the program is parsing a line from the file and re-outputting as a pipe-separated file.

But, this program deals with each line as a complete record. That might be fine for you, but at some point you might end up with a literal value that has a newline in it, like `a,"b\nc",d`. Now reading line-by-line breaks the program since the quotes appear to be unclosed within the first line. Note only that, it blindly concatenates the parsed fields without considering if any of the fields should be quoted. It might be unlikely that a pipe character would be in the data, but the problem isn't it's rarity but the consequences and costliness when it does show up.

The [rewrite.pl](https://github.com/Tux/Text-CSV_XS/blob/master/examples/rewrite.pl) example script in the related module [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) is a tool that could replace this one-liner. It properly reads the input and knows how to properly translate it.